# std::out_of_range: vector exception in Mergesort algorithm

Tags: c++

I am trying to implement the Mergesort algorithm in C++. You can see my implementation below. When I run the algorithm I get the following error:

`libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::out_of_range: vector
Abort trap: 6`

While this is my first time working in C++, I assume that this error means that I pass in an index that is outside the bounds of some vector. Is this correct?

If this is correct, I cannot figure out where I am exceeding the bounds of some vector. However, I printed a few values to the console and noticed that the program fails to print the elements in the vector right. Maybe this gives a hint for where the index is out of bounds.

**Mergesort implementation**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void merge(std::vector<int> left, std::vector<int> right, std::vector<int> array)
{
    int lengthLeft = left.size();
    int lengthRight = right.size();

    int i = 0; // index of smallest unpicked element in left
    int j = 0; // index of smallest unpicked element in right
    int k = 0; // position to be filled in array
    while (i < lengthLeft && j < lengthRight)
    {
        if (left.at(i) <= right.at(j))
        {
            array.at(k) = left.at(i);
            k++;
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            array.at(k) = right.at(j);
            k++;
            j++;
        }
    }
    while (i < lengthLeft)
    {
        array.at(k) = left.at(i);
        k++;
        i++;
    }
    while (j < lengthRight)
    {
        array.at(k) = right.at(j);
        k++;
        j++;
    }
}

std::vector<int> mergesort(std::vector<int> array)
{
    int length = array.size();
    std::cout << "Array Size: " << length << '\n';

    if (length < 2)
    {
        return array;
    }

    int mid = length / 2;
    std::cout << "mid = " << mid << '\n';

    // Temporary vectors.
    std::vector<int> left(mid);
    std::vector<int> right(length - mid);
    std::cout << "Left size: " << left.size() << '\n';
    std::cout << "Right size: " << right.size() << '\n';

    // Moving elements into temporary vectors.
    for (int i = 0; i <= mid; i++)
    {
        left.at(i) = array.at(i);
        std::cout << "Left at i: " << left.at(i) << '\n';
    }
    for (int i = mid + 1; i < length; i++)
    {
        right.at(i) = array.at(i);
        std::cout << "Right at i: " << right.at(i) << '\n'; // <-- THIS DOES NOT PRINT
    }

    mergesort(left);
    mergesort(right);
    merge(left, right, array);

    return array;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vect = {5, 4, 3, 2, 1};

    for (int i : vect)
    {
        std::cout << i << " " << '\n';
    }

    mergesort(vect);

    for (int i : vect)
    {
        std::cout << i << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Console output**

```
5
4
3
2
1
Array Size: 5
mid = 2
Left size: 2
Right size: 3
Left at i: 5
Left at i: 4
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::out_of_range: vector
Abort trap: 6
```

Comment: Why don't you debug your program? It will show where the error happened.

Comment: You should really base you merge sort on iterators.  All of this copying you are doing is going to kill your performance.

Comment: On related note, you might want to read about references, because by default all types behave as "value types" and so the parameters are copied. Which is in contrast with Java or C#.

Comment: Your `merge` function effectively does nothing useful - you are making modifications to the copies of the objects, that get discarded  at the end of the function.

Comment: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: @Damien Don't I? Don't the conditions for the while loops test exactly that?

Comment: @Quimby I have been working without an IDE. I will get one now so that I can debug my code properly.

Comment: @K.Claesson "_I have been working without an IDE._" You don't need IDE to debug your code. There exist multiple standalone debuggers out there: gdb, windbg, cdb.

Comment: Line 61 `for (int i = 0; i <= mid; i++)`: `left`have a size of `mid`, not `mid+1`. I hope this comment is correct this time.

Comment: @Damien I think it should be `mid` because in the left vector I pass in the elements from  0 to `mid` and in the right vector I pass in the elements from `mid + 1` to `length - 1`.

Comment: At the time being, you are trying to pass `mid+1` values in left and `length - mid - 1` values in right.  But the vectors were not dimensioned like that.

Comment: That is true. I fixed that now, but the same error still remains though.

Comment: Pay attention to the comments of NathanOlivier and Algirdas Preidzius

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few things wrong with your code, but the error is being given by this loops

```
for (int i = 0; i <= mid; i++)
{
    left.at(i) = array.at(i);
    std::cout << "Left at i: " << left.at(i) << '\n';
}
for (int i = mid + 1; i < length; i++)
{
    right.at(i) = array.at(i);
    std::cout << "Right at i: " << right.at(i) << '\n'; // <-- THIS DOES NOT PRINT
}
```

To fix your error you have to change the first for to `for (int i = 0; i < mid; i++)` replacing the `<=` with just `<`, so it gets the first two digits.
On the second you should change to `for (int i = 0; i < length - mid; i++)` also change `right.at(i) = array.at(i);` to `right.at(i) = array.at(mid + i);`, this will make sure you get the remaining 3, the problem here was that you were starting in `mid` which was `2` and the `right` vector only has size of `3`, since vector are indexed at 0 you were starting on the last index and the next iteration was out of the bounds of it.

So the hole section would be like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < mid; i++)
{
    left.at(i) = array.at(i);
    std::cout << "Left at i: " << left.at(i) << '\n';
}
for (int i = 0; i < length - mid; i++)
{
    right.at(i) = array.at(mid + i);
    std::cout << "Right at i: " << right.at(i) << '\n'; // <-- THIS DOES NOT PRINT
}
```

That being said your program wouldn't still sort the vector, C++ passes arguments by value, that means that every time you call a function with a certain input it will create a **new** variable with the same data.
Your `mergesort` function is supposed to receive a vector and change the values on it, here you have two options, or change the function to return a new vector or you pass the vector to this function by reference, using `&`, this instead of creating a new vector inside the function with the same values, will send the memory reference of the variable to the function, that way the function has access to the same variable.
Your function should be changed to

```
void merge(std::vector<int> &left, std::vector<int> &right, std::vector<int> &array)
{ ... }

std::vector<int> mergesort(std::vector<int> &array)
{ ... }
```

Some times will be useful to pass by reference other not, you will get that in time, but usually performance-wise it's a good practice because you are not creating new variables with each function.

If it wasn't clear or you want a better explanation just ask.

#### Tip

Careful naming your variables, you shouldn't use <s>reserved</s> names, `array` is a name <s>reserved</s> by C++, you should have another name instead.

It's not actually a reserved word, only conflicts if the programmer uses `using namespace std`, as stated by @user4581301

> Reserved is a loaded term. In C++ Reserved means you can't use this, no matter what. array is not reserved. Using array as an identifier will only cause problems if  is included and the std namespace has been short-circuited with using namespace std (something the wise programmer avoids).

Comment: A quick correction to the Tip: Reserved is a loaded term. In C++ Reserved means you can't use this, no matter what. `array` is not reserved. Using `array` as an identifier will only cause problems if `<array>` is included and the `std` namespace has been short-circuited with `using namespace std` ([something the wise programmer avoids](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)). That said, it's a good tip. Exercise caution when using the identifiers of common data types.

Comment: Let me see if I have understood this correctly. When I prefix the vector names with an ``&`` they are passed by reference. This makes the function that they are passed into modify the state of the memory allocation that was assigned and configured for the vectors upon their initialization because the vector parameters ``&left``, ``&right`` and ``&array`` are actually memory addresses that point to the original vectors. The way I had written the code I passed the vectors by value which meant that a new memory allocation with the same state as the old one was created....

Comment: This caused unexpected behavior as I continued creating new vectors and losing the old ones. Have I understood this mostly correctly?

Comment: @K.Claesson yes you did, using the `&` actually passes the memory address of that vector instead of creating a new vector exactly with the same data. Exactly like you said `&left, &right and &array are actually memory addresses that point to the original vectors`